# React doesn't start if page reloaded on route with parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have problem with my app in development mode on localhost. If I reload the app on a route with param, e.g.:

```
localhost:8080/item/2
```

React doesnt even start, only blank page is rendered.

But If I do reload page on any other page without params, e.g.:

```
/home
/about
```

the page is rendered correctly and React app starts successfully.

**Note**: Im not getting any errrors in console, the app basically doesnt even start, the root id for React is simply empty.

### Edit:

my route for the `item` page:

```
<Route path={['/', '/item/:id']} exact component={ItemPage} />
```

Comment: ['/', '/item/:id'] what does mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you split that into two `Route`s and wrap it with `Switch`?

```
<Switch>
<Route path={'/'} exact component={ItemPage} />
<Route path={'/item/:id'} component={ItemPage} />
<Switch>
```

Honestly I haven't seen `exact` and `'/item/:id'` prop used together and that might be an issue

Comment: Unfortunately didnt help :(

Comment: What does it show? When you inspect elements does it render anything inside root?

Comment: Nope, nothing is rendered inside root